# Flutter Web - Unsupported operation: NaN error for canvas in Card widget

Tags: flutter, canvas, flutter-web, card, fl-chart

I am working on a flutter web project. We use the library [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart). We would like to use a `PieChart` in a `Card` widget but it throws the error `Unsupported operation: NaN`. It happens in debug and release mode (launched from the command lines `flutter run lib/main.dart` and `flutter run --release lib/main.dart`) but it doesn't happen when the application is launched through the VSCode debugger.

Here is a small example (`main.dart`):

```dart
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PieChartTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Card(    // <- If you change it to a Container, it is working fine
          child: PieChart(
            PieChartData(
              sections: [
                PieChartSectionData(
                  value: 4.0,
                  title: 'Section 1',
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                PieChartSectionData(
                  value: 6.0,
                  title: 'Section 2',
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(PieChartTest());
}
```

Here are the logs

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following UnsupportedError was thrown during a scheduler callback:
Unsupported operation: NaN

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 216:49  throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/js_number.dart 80:5             toInt]
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/js_number.dart 87:32            ceil]
lib/_engine/engine/bitmap_canvas.dart 176:52
_widthToPhysical
lib/_engine/engine/bitmap_canvas.dart 120:32                                  new
lib/_engine/engine/html/picture.dart 518:33
[_findOrCreateCanvas]
lib/_engine/engine/html/picture.dart 433:21
paintCallback
lib/_engine/engine/html/surface.dart 49:16
commitScene
lib/_engine/engine/html/scene_builder.dart 552:7                              <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/profiler.dart 36:18
timeAction
lib/_engine/engine/html/scene_builder.dart 546:12                             build
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 770:35
buildScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/view.dart 231:30
compositeFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 458:18                            drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 900:13                              drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 320:5
[_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1119:15
[_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1057:9
handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 865:7                             <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19
internalCallback
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
═════════════
Another exception was thrown: Unsupported operation: NaN
```

I'm using the Flutter 1.25.0-8.1.pre beta

---

What is it happening and why ?

And also how can I fix this or is there any work around ?

---

EDIT:

It also doesn't work with Flutter `1.25.0-8.3.pre • channel beta` and hits the same issue.
It works on Flutter `1.26.0-17.1.pre • channel dev` .

But the project we use needs the beta channel.

It works using the option `--web-renderer canvaskit` but I would like to continue to use the `html` one.

Comment: I'm using Flutter  1.26.0-1.0.pre dev and it works fine.

Comment: Hey, I just want to check, did you use the command lines as I described in my question or did you use the integrated debugger of your IDE ?

Comment: Yes, I used command line.

Comment: I just tried with Flutter `1.25.0-8.3.pre • channel beta` and hit the same issue :/ I actually works on  `1.26.0-17.1.pre • channel dev ` . But the project we use needs the beta channel. I have updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not supported by the HTML Web Renderer.

Try with the CanvasKit Web Renderer instead.

`flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit .\lib\main.dart`

Comment: It actually worked ! But I'm not sure it won't break anything else if we use it to build our production app

Comment: In the end, this is the solution we used. Thank you !

Comment: Same package, some problem. Somebody @me if they find a fix outside of using canvaskit please.

Answer (score 0):

This is working well even in debug mode.

[image]

Though, am using the `stable version` 1.22.5.

Comment: Hey, I just want to check, did you use the command lines I described in my question or did you use the integrated debugger of your IDE ?

Comment: Yeah. I did it through the command `flutter run lib/main.dart`

Comment: I just tried with Flutter `1.25.0-8.3.pre • channel beta` and hit the same issue :/ I actually works on  `1.26.0-17.1.pre • channel dev ` . But the project we use needs the beta channel. I have updated my post accordingly.